# JIRA Mark ticket as Accepted/Acknowledge

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I've been looking for a way to have a user acknowledge a 
ticket after it has been assigned to them. I don't know if 
this is a built in feature or if there is a plugin that 
will create a state/button for a user to accept a ticket 
after it has been put in there queue. I would expect to 
see something like this from the ticket window around 
workflow or start progress but no amounts of digging 
through configuration settings has turned anything 
relevant up.

Does anyone know about this added functionality in JIRA?
Much thanks.

Comment: I did this by custom workflow step. After an issue arrived to an assignee (with status `New`) he/she should move it to another step (with status `Open`). Until he/she does it, the issue is considered as not noticed/reached the assignee. Also I have had a report showing issues with `New` status for more than a predefined period of time. If this helps, I can post an answer.

Comment: Very much would appreciate that as an answer, I believe we can utilize this in our workflow as a solid way for assignee's to accept a ticket. If possible, please list the steps you used. Cheers.

Comment: It's also useful to know you can have a workflow with a transition back to the same status. You can use that idea to display a big Accept button that then sets a field in the issue or some such post function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this by a custom workflow step. After an issue arrived to an assignee (with status `New`) he/she should move it to another step (with status `Open`). Until he/she does it, the issue is considered as not noticed/reached the assignee. Also I have had a report showing issues with `New` status for more than a predefined period of time.

I'm not aware of a ready-made plugin which performs similar task (perhaps, I should dig into my posts on Atlassian answers to discover some clues for other solutions).

Answer (score 0):

As @Stan says above, a custom workflow is the way to implement this.  The workflow functionality in JIRA is very flexible and as a result has a bit of a learning curve, but [Atlassian's documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA051/Configuring+Workflow) is pretty good.  Post back here if you need help.